# PIL pillow open bmp image returns an inverted image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have two datsets on separate folders containing handwriting words, inspecting them by an image viewer I can see that the background is white and the script is black.

After reading them, one image is inverted and the other is not. I think this is a bug in the PIL/Pillow library. Or, I am missing something here?

```
from PIL import Image
...
img = Image.open('the_image.bmp')
```

Comment: How can you tell it's inverted?

Comment: @Kevin By viewing the values inside iPython.

Comment: @Kevin these are handwriting word images, so it is easy to tell the inversion. I do not mind if all the images are negative/inverted the same wise, but one set is the contrary of the other.

Comment: Did the images come from the same source? Possibly the data sets have differently configured headers, and PIL is only correctly interpreting one of them. But this isn't too likely if they all came from the same webcam, or whatever.

Comment: @Kevin Yes. The images are from the same source. One thing that could mak this to happen, which is a problem in the original images, is that the max gray-value (maxG) is 1 in four folders, but 255 in one folder (each folder has like 6000 images). The background in the loaded images that have maxG value 1  is zero, but, the background in the loaded images that have maxG value 255 is 255! 
I know this since I did some exploratory analysis and produced five histograms for the five folders.

Comment: The GNOME image viewer shows images with white background and dark script, for all images in all folders.
So, if the problem is in the way the images are stored, how can the image viewer figure out how to display them?!

Comment: If your image viewer and PIL disagree about the contents of your image, then it really might be a bug. You might consider submitting a bug report, although they'll probably ask you to upload an image that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Kevin I am still inspecting this, as I have reshaped the image with numpy, maybe this is the cause of the problem, during unint8 casting, here's the line:
`img = np.array(img.getdata(),
                    np.uint8).reshape(img.size[1], img.size[0], 1)  `

Comment: `BMP` was *"designed"* by Microsoft who occasionally don't do things in the industry standard way, and in this case, the raster is stored upside-down (i.e. starting at the bottom of the screen) relative to just about every other image format. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format